# Are uncommon neologisms without a notable source acceptable as an answer?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-off-topic

Example questions:

- [Is there a word for words about words?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/207992/is-there-a-word-for-words-about-words/208039#208039)
- [Who is one who participates in skulduggery?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/206487/who-is-one-who-participates-in-skulduggery/206507#206507)

Accepted answers in these questions are very uncommon neologisms from random websites. I would consider they are not notable.

So do we accept any neologism if it is at least used in a random website or a very few random websites? [for example, not even an article but used in a comment from a random user]

Does the community welcome/approve these answers and are these answers acceptable?

I give answers that are neologisms too but I usually give that answer when there is a notable source like a publication in Google Books. [For example, some of them are used in several books or in a significant amount of websites some of which have an article that use the word] [You might discuss here that if a book in Google Books is any more notable than a website].

What are your opinions about the example questions that I mentioned and about this topic?

<sub>Note: I neither favor nor disfavor these kind of answers. I'm asking your opinions first.</sub>

---

Related questions:

- [Is it fine to ask questions about neologism and new words morphology here?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4290/is-it-fine-to-ask-questions-about-neologism-and-new-words-morphology-here)
- [When are neologisms On-Topic?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4026/when-are-neologisms-on-topic)

Comment: You're going to have to pry *[hoaxpitality](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/189896/is-there-a-word-for-fake-kindness-or-hospitality/189929#189929)* from my cold, dead hands. And the world would be a poorer place without @Joe Blow's *[cyphobe](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/189642/word-for-discrimination-based-on-partly-consisting-of-mechanical-parts/189667#189667)*.

Comment: @DanBron: There is a fine line between _neologomania_ and creativity then?

Comment: Can you explain how those two linked questions don't handle yours already?

Comment: @Mitch: I didn't get your question. Oh, you mean related questions. This is a specific case of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I originally left my response on 'word for words about words' as a comment, since it was not well-sourced or found in significant use; I only converted to an answer at the OP's explicit request, as he (?) apparently deemed it to be sufficient to his needs.

However, I am unclear as to who this "we" is that you are referring to when you say

> So do we accept any neologism if it is at least used in a random website?

The only person who accepted it was the OP; I'm not sure who else you think should be accepting it, or how this acceptance would take place.  If you think it's a bad answer, you are fully entitled to downvote and/or comment on how unsuitable it is.

If the alternative to "accepting any neologism" is that all "under-sourced" neologisms should be flagged as "not an answer" and deleted, though, then I will have to say that I believe that should not happen; in some cases there is not a word available for the meaning they seek, and in some cases making one up is actually a reasonable thing to do, especially when the meaning is readily derivable.

Comment: "We" is the community. I'm asking everyone's opinion. I didn't say I'm against it. I never down-voted those kind of answers also.

Comment: "We" the community don't accept the answer, the OP does, so I also don't understand what you mean by "accept"; how is the community supposed to accept or reject the answer, or how is it expected to act toward an 'unworthy' answer?

Comment: "Accept" means approving/welcoming here. Does the community welcome/approve these answers and are these answers acceptable? I'm asking a general question, not only accepting the answer of a particular question.

Comment: Since the U in ELU is about usage, and it would be ridiculous to overly broaden what this means (I used to use it as a code-word for 'scrumping' with my best friend), my view is that inclusion in at least Wiktionary (or, if my arm is twisted, UD) should be considered necessary. This in the interests of non-mediocrity. Note that the words 'pseudo-word' and 'non-word' exist; 'neologism' is usually defined as 'a candidate recently adopted into the lexicon'.

Comment: From @nohat: 'While I'm not entirely opposed to “single word requests” I get pretty anxious when I see questions like this one, where there is (to my knowledge) no real answer, and then people take this as an invitation to start coining words.
I really don't feel comfortable at all with our site becoming a place where people go who want a word invented. While I delight in exciting new words being invented and promulgated, I think we will rapidly lose our reputation as a place where people can get authoritative answers if many answers are not authoritative but just merely inventive.'